# what is the application property setting to connect mysql in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

what is the application property setting to connect mysql in spring boot

I also want to generate the table automatically

I'm receiving this error in Spring Boot -Application properties I created Spring Boot starter project-Maven and opened application properties it shows Failed to create parts control please help how to solve this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at springs guide [Accessing data with MySQL](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql).

This guide also provides you with the following template for the applications.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```